# lightning:recordEditForm, mark as missing a field that I'm passing

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, javascript-controller, create-records

I have an Issue with this component. When every Try to submit a new OpportunityLineItem
The component sends the following error messages.

```
An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.
ProdConfigCreateOppItem.js:59 undefined
ProdConfigCreateOppItem.js:60 REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING
ProdConfigCreateOppItem.js:61 Required fields are missing: [OpportunityId]
```

The problem is that I'm actually sending the required fields, also, I've tried Intercepting the request, and adding the fields manually in an `onsubmit` function.
I read the component documentation and no hint about this.

Any Idea what It's wrong?

```
<lightning:recordEditForm
        onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
        onerror="{!c.getError}"
        objectApiName="OpportunityLineItem"
        aura:id="createOppItem">
        <lightning:messages />

        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Product2Id" /> 
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="UnitPrice" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quantity" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="ServiceDate" /> 
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Description" /> 
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="OpportunityId" value="{!v.oppId}"/>
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Add" />
        </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: Is the OpportunityId correct in the `fields` parameter in your `onsubmit` handler before you set it manually? Or does it come through blank when the form is submitted?

Comment: The problem absolutely looks to be in the framework as how the default `submit` is being handled. I was able to replicate the issue that you are having if using what you have here. But when I customized the create process using a custom apex aura method, I was able to pass all the values and was able to create a new opportunity line item without any issue.

Comment: Actually, that was the only workaround, I could find, using the onsubmit, and preventing default instead using an aura enabled method, but,well that is not the point of the recordEditForm, I am looking how can I submit the issue on the developer community.

Comment: You will need to open a case to the support

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to use recordId attribute for lightning:recordEditForm.I am not very much sure on this.since you have not posted entire code.PFB my sample code.i am also doing the same thing and its working.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              objectApiName="Location_Contact__c" 
                              onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
        <div class="slds-media">

            <div class="slds-media__body">

                <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Prefix__c"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="First_Name__c"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Last_Name__c"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Title__c"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                </lightning:layout>
                <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center" class="slds-m-top_large">
                    <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" type="text" onclick="{!c.gotoURL}"/>
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" title="Save" type="submit"/>
                </lightning:layout>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: According to the documentation, when no ID provided, It is a creating record form.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm

Comment: You don't need to provide the `recordId` attribute if the component is used to create a new record, which is what OP has mentioned -- *Try to submit a new OpportunityLineItem*